# Python Pandas plot multiindex specify x and y

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Below is an example `DataFrame`.

```
           joaquin     manolo
xx 0  0.000000e+00  44.000000
   1  1.570796e+00  52.250000
   2  3.141593e+00  60.500000
   3  4.712389e+00  68.750000
   4  6.283185e+00  77.000000
yy 0  0.000000e+00  37.841896
   1  2.078796e+00  39.560399
   2  5.292179e-17  41.026434
   3 -8.983291e-02  42.304767
   4 -4.573916e-18  43.438054
```

As you can see, the row index has two levels, `['xx', 'yy']` and `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. I want to call `DataFrame.plot()` in such a way that it will produce two subplots, one for `joaquin` and one for `manolo`, and where I can specify to use `data.loc["xx", :]` for the domain data and to use `data.loc["yy", :]` for the ordinate data. In addition, I want the option to supply the subplots on which the plots should be drawn, in a list (or array) of `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` instances, such as those that can be returned by the `DataFrame.hist()` method. How can this be done?

#### Generating the data above

Just in case you're wondering, below is the code I used to generate the data. If there is an easier way to generate this data, I'd be very interested to know as a side-note.

```
joaquin_dict = {}
xx_joaquin = numpy.linspace(0, 2*numpy.pi, 5)
yy_joaquin = 10 * numpy.sin(xx_joaquin) * numpy.exp(-xx_joaquin)
for i in range(len(xx_joaquin)):
    joaquin_dict[("xx", i)] = xx_joaquin[i]
    joaquin_dict[("yy", i)] = yy_joaquin[i]

manolo_dict = {}
xx_manolo = numpy.linspace(44, 77, 5)
yy_manolo = 10 * numpy.log(xx_manolo)
for i in range(len(xx_manolo)):
    manolo_dict[("xx", i)] = xx_manolo[i]
    manolo_dict[("yy", i)] = yy_manolo[i]

data_dict = {"joaquin": joaquin_dict, "manolo": manolo_dict}
data = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a for loop:

```
fig, axes = pl.subplots(1, 2)
for ax, col in zip(axes, data.columns):
    data[col].unstack(0).plot(x="xx", y="yy", ax=ax, title=col)
```

output:

[image]